# Do journals issue any certificate when they publish an article?

Tags: publications, journals

I am new to this field. I have published one review paper in a journal recently. Do journals issue certificates after publishing manuscripts?

Comment: What do you mean, issuing a certificate?  Do you mean an acknowledgement of your review?

Comment: Why would they? Isn't the paper itself enough proof that you indeed published in the journal?

Comment: A certificate of *what*?

Comment: @Raakh As Saturnus said the paper itself is a proof. However, if you are publishing with Elsevier you can download the certificate yourself by providing the necessary information. I am not sure about the others.

Comment: Which field are you new to?

Comment: Can you not simply provide the citation or DOI for the paper. The article itself should attest to your expertise and having been accepted in a well known jourmal5 with peer review. Although this will be more relevant for original research than a review. Although if it was an invited review that would be worth mentioning on your CV.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Generally, once you have a manuscript published, you don't receive a certificate, but you get something far better and far more practical - a published paper that would be read by a wider audience and potentially, cited (which can be considered as validation of your work).  Additionally and importantly, you'll have a bibliographic record that you can add to a website, CV, Christmas Card etc. - that is a true 'certificate' or your work.

Having said all that, a little while ago, I received a small A4 'certificate' for having an article published as a featured article - but that is very journal specific.

Comment: Normally you would give the bibliographic information about the article.  That is your "certificate".  Then anyone can find it.  If the journal is so obscure that it cannot easily be found, perhaps you can put a copy of the article on your web site as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What did you do with this certificate? Did anyone ever asked for it?

Comment: If it was an article I was particularly proud of, I'd probably see if I could get a high-quality reprint, either digital or on paper, that matches the layout of the journal including the other material on the respective pages, and frame that. Given that many journals publish articles as downloadable PDFs, that should be easy and likely something you can do yourself, if only you have access to a reasonably high-quality printer (which almost all are, these days).

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog the certificate is in a folder on my desk, and I have never been asked for it.